# Extracting specific data from a [pandas.core.frame.DataFrame] variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

While extracting data from a .csv file using pandas, I wanted to collect the labels of various columns in that file. Instead of hardcoding, I was trying to extract it from the variable I created from the code below:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("Anydatasheet.csv")
features = ["Pclass","Age", "Fare", "Parch", "SibSp","Sex","Embarked"]
X = pd.get_dummies(train_data[features])
X.head()
```

(By labels above, I mean the bold text circled in the image attached)

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

(Image data source : Kaggle titanic problem data)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RND7Y.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your intention: do you mean the headers (columns in csv)? or the list of possible options for every column (e.g Sex will be "Male"/"Female")? or something else? please provide example of input and output

Comment: By headers I meant the bold text that appears when X.head() is run ; For clarification, I'm attaching image now pls refer to it. I was aking about the text highlighted with red circles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the columns names. You can read them directly:

```py
train_data = pd.read_csv("Anydatasheet.csv")
features_name = train_data.columns
```

or if you want them as python regular list:

```py
train_data = pd.read_csv("Anydatasheet.csv")
features_name = train_data.columns.tolist()
```

example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"city":[1,1], "A":[5,6]})
print(df.columns.tolist())
```

output:

```py
['city', 'A']
```